# Make PEAR use github channel

Tags: php, github, pear

I just found out (wow) that PEAR packages are being moved to Github, my pear packages have not given any problems, until today when I decided after a long while to update them and there was no update for them (I last did this over a year ago).

Maybe it's because I'm not familiar with how PEAR works to being with, but how do you tell it to use the PEAR channel in Github? After some googling around I've tried multiple variations of the following with no luck

```
pear channel-discover https://github.com/pear/
```

To show a concrete example, I use the Net_FTP package, which in the pear repository was last updated in 2008, whereas the version in github shows an update from 3 months ago.

Am I missing something? Shouldn't had PEAR added this channel automatically? How can I make my PEAR use the Github version of my packages? or do I need to clone those repositories manually in my shared libraries directory?

Comment: Only the source code is moving to GitHub.

Comment: So I have to pull from the repo manually? or do they commit back to the normal channel (ie the svn repo) at some point in time?

Comment: Default channel has not moved:  `pear.php.net`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code of the packages only moved to git, not the package releases themselves.

Github will show newer commits, but commits != releases - you will have to wait for package releases to be made to get the latest source code changes.

This is not different than it was the last 12 years when we used SVN (and previously CVS) to host the code. They just were not that visible as github is.